# OPENLDAP 2.4 , allow anonymous access only to get User Publickey

Tags: ssh, ldap, openldap, access-control-list

I'm trying to do the following :
I have openldap 2.4.45 server (test) which contains users, groups like this :

```
o=Example(dc=example,dc=com)
  ou=users
    uid=alice
    uid=bob
      PublicKey="...."
  ou=Groups
    cn=group1
    cn=group2
```

I need to connect an application to this server. Some users in DIT have a publicKey (like bob), what I want is that anonymous bind can get PublicKey of any user if it knows exactly the DN (for instance dn:uid=bob,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com), but I'dont want anonymous bind to be able to read other attributes

I tried to do the following

```
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword by self write by anonymous auth by * none
olcAccess: {1}to attrs=shadowLastChange by self write by * read
olcAccess: {2}to attrs=PublicKey by * read stop
olcAccess: {3}to * by * none
```

But when I try this request

```
ldapsearch -x -b "dc=example,dc=com" -LLL '(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid='"bob"'))' 'PublicKey'
```

I get a "No such object (32)" , but if I allow access to * by * read i get the PublicKey for user bob..

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to

1. grant at least `search` right to the search root entry `dc=example,dc=com`
2. grant `read` right to pseudo-attribute *entry* of the entry containing the attribute *PublicKey*

Comment: Then maybe mark the answer as accepted so others can perceive it as solution?

Comment: excuse me for my oversight !